# What is the escape sequence for & in string literals in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

What is the escape sequence for &-sign in string literals in web.config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a list of the XML document escape characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Comment: This answers does adress your issue: [escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177861/escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-string#answer-10142361)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

& -> `&amp;`

here: [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 6):

Use `"&amp;"` instead of `"&"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the `&amp;` doesn't work in web.config, it must have stricter rules than normal XML:

```
<add key="ST_CF_AppType_ipad" value="http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/itunes-u/id490217893?l=en&amp;mt=8" />
```

Gives an error occurred while parsing `EntityName`.

Comment: -1 because this is not correct. `<add key="ST_CF_AppType_ipad" value="http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/itunes-u/id490217893?l=en&amp;mt=8"/>` works fine in a Web.Config file. (Tested with the above appSetting in .NET 4.0 MVC app - but it should be the same in other framework versions.)