# Using sign (") and sign (') in database connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string, double-quotes, quote

My database(Sql compact edition) password is `Y6K<dkq2J)[hf/',@K"!IiQA`.
When I create it's entity data model connection string in my App config will be:

**Edited**

```
<add name="OtherEntities" ... Password=&quot;&quot;Y6K&lt;dkq2J)[hf/',@K&quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;!IiQA&quot;&quot;  ... />
```

There are quotation sign `"` and `'` in the password,every thing is OK.so i want to use Ado.Net `SqCelconnection`.

```
            string pass = "???";
            string conString =
                "Data Source=path\Other.sdf;password='" + pass + "';";
            using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
            {
.
```

How do I replace `"` sign  and `'` sign in password?

I already tried  `\"`,`\"\"`,`&quot;` for `"` sign.

and `''` and `&apos;` for `'` sign.but doesn't work.

Comment: Check Update 3 to the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3177871/55209

Comment: You have to options.  The first use a different password the second use an escape character.

Comment: @Ramhound:i wont to change pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to make the string yourself because of those escape and quote characters within the string.

This seemed to work:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"Y6K<dkq2J)[hf/',@K");
sb.Append((char)34);
sb.Append("!IiQA");

string conString = @"Data Source=path\Other.sdf;password=" + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you,but `sb.Append(@"Y6K<dkq2J)[hf/'',@K");` must be `sb.Append(@"Y6K<dkq2J)[hf/',@K");`(one sing ' removed).

Comment: @irsog Updated for the sake of correctness.  Hard password to crack even when looking at it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you [may not be able to have single and double quotation marks in the same connections string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/important-rules-for-connection-strings).

Comment: i already read this,i already use this with app.conf no problem,but why can not use ado.net?

Comment: @irsog: in which case try `var pass = "Y6K<dkq2J)[hf/',@K\"!IiQA";`.