# web.config transformation breaks connection string with special symbols

Tags: .net, connection-string, web.config-transform

My SQL-server password for example looks like `ABcDE1e]"L` and in connection string it escaped as `ABcDE1e]&quot;L`.

But after web.config transformation it become looks like `ABcDE1e]&amp;quot;L`.

Why it decoded twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`'ABcDE1e]&quot;;L.'`

[See if this SO helps (Escape quote in web.config connection string):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177861/escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-string)