# Escaping double quotes in connection string in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my .NET 5 web application my appsettings.json connection string is as follows:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=.; Database=XKCDPublicDb; user id=nitin;password=\"XKCDDUMMY}Xb\"f~\""
}
```

as you can see the password contains double quotes, so I escaped using `\"` but still I am getting following error:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 49.
ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 49. STACK TRACE: at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<BeginTransaction>b__0(DatabaseFacade database) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, IsolationLevel isolationLevel) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.CreateDbContext[TDbContext](String connectionString, IDbContextResolver dbContextResolver) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.GetOrCreateDbContext[TDbContext](Nullable`1 multiTenancySide, String name) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkExtensions.GetDbContext[TDbContext](IActiveUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Nullable`1 multiTenancySide, String name) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`1.GetDbContext(Nullable`1 multiTenancySide) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetContext() at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.<GetQueryable>b__7_0(Type key) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetQueryable() at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetAllIncluding(Expression`1[] propertySelectors) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetAll() at NS.Public.NSRepository.LogVisit(String ip) in C:\Users\Nitin\source\repos\NS\public\src\NS.Public.Application\NSRepository.cs:line 43 at NS.Public.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\Nitin\source\repos\NS\public\src\NS.Public.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 44 at lambda_method87(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

[image]

Comment: try replacing the double quote with `&quot;` Had to do this with .Net Framework connection strings to escape special XML characters.

Comment: @phuzi this is a JSON string, not XML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape quote in web.config connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177861/escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surrounded the password with single quote `'` and it worked

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=.; Database=XKCDPublicDb; user id=nitin;password='XKCDDUMMY}Xb\"f~'"
}
```