# Password containing left angle bracket causing issues in web.config file asp.net

Tags: connection-string

Hi I am trying to build a connectionstring in web.config file in MVC. Everything is fine except that I have to use autogenerated password and latest password has left angle bracket. When I am using this password containing left angle bracket, the connectionstring does not build correctly and I face failed connection.
"Data Source=JungJu.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MainDb;User ID=FuntoGo;Password=OV_Xu2v8j2K$@~/<bI,A]d;Authentication=Active Directory Password

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177861/escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-string/10142361#10142361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with

```
&lt;
```

is is the XML safe replacement for < (less than)