# Microsoft Azure + OleDB + FoxPro

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, foxpro

I have a solution that talks to a FoxPro database (dbc) table (dbf) via the MS OleDb provider.  Recently we would like to roll this solution out to MS Azure but it says the provider is not installed.

> Exception: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.
>   It may not be installed.

Any idea hot to get this installed? The solution runs on my local machine without errors. I've googled this but unable to find anything specific - however I did see articles that indicated OleDb is not supported yet can be installed.

**Here is the direct error message i'm getting on the azure website**

> The underlying provider failed on Open. The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: what does your connection string look like have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085811/why-doesnt-microsoft-support-ole-db-connections-to-sql-azure

Comment: Yes, saw that post - it's specifically referring to sql azure + oledb.   My question is mainly about istalling OleDb on hte azure web server.

Comment: Connection string:  <add name="datadbcContext" connectionString="data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|/Containers/data.dbc&quot;" providerName="VfpEntityFrameworkProvider" />    --- -This works locally on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure might be running on x64 bit OS. You need to have an Ole DB provider for foxpro that works well for x64 OS. or you can change it to x86 OS

Comment: Azure Server is definitely 32-bit OS - verified... how would you install OleDb onto either version? Preferably 32-bit?

Comment: try using WIndows 2003 Server OS if available

Comment: I'm using Azure "Websites" not a Virtual Machine... is that still an option?

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot in that case you cannot install it. OLE DB is COM based and requires registry modifications to be correctly registered, you cannot simply upload the DLLs.

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot you might consider this as an opportunity to migrate from a discontinued product.

Comment: why not SQL Linked servers instead? so you can access the DB via MSSQL acting as bridge to your VFP DB

Comment: @Simpicio - I believe this still requires the VFP driver.

Comment: @Eli  -   Not in my control to migrate to newer platform.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is Microsoft's cloud version of a SQL-Server database, so to connect to that you'll need SQL driver not VFP's OleDB.  Now if you need to query one table in VFP and another that is in Azure, I do not believe you can ... even if both are 32-bit, and VFP will only ever be 32-bit anyhow.  If you do need to query between both, it would have to be done in a 3-part process I guess.  Query from Azure to .Net (like a DataTable result), query from VFP (also to DataTable), then you could manually scroll through the rows and get what you need, such as with LINQ.